# No session id found - Yodlee login IAV API

Tags: yodlee

I get a "No session id found" response when I invoke [login](https://rest.developer.yodlee.com/services/srest/restserver/v1.0/authenticate/login) API. I ensured the cobsessiontoken is valid and not empty but Yodlee's service thinks that the field is empty.

```
    HttpPost httpPost2 = new HttpPost(yodleeURL+login);
    List<NameValuePair> nvps2 =new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    System.out.println(yodleeURL+login);
    nvps2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "cobSessionToken"));
    System.out.println(sessionToken);
    nvps2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("value", sessionToken));

    nvps2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "login"));
    nvps2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("value", "xxxxxxx"));

    nvps2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "password"));
    nvps2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("value", "xxxxxxx"));

    UrlEncodedFormEntity encodedURL =  new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps2);
    httpPost2.setEntity(encodedURL);
    CloseableHttpResponse response2 = httpclient.execute(httpPost2);
    JsonElement element1 = new      JsonParser().parse(EntityUtils.toString(response2.getEntity()));
    JsonObject  jobject1 = element1.getAsJsonObject();
    System.out.println(jobject1.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

This response comes when you are not passing 'cobSessionToken' as an input param or passing it incorrectly.
If you are passing then please make sure its casing is also correct as it is case-sensitive.

Though, as per your code it seems like you are passing the param name correctly

Comment: I pass the cobSessionToken as returned by coblogin call - no changes to the case. Is it possible for a developer to look at the stack trace of the log on Yodlee server to understand if the parameters are missing or empty?

Comment: @Ashish I would recommend you to check the param key names not the values, as this error comes when something is wrong with the name of the param key( in your case- cobSessionToken), also please try once with any REST clients like Advance REST client or PostMan and see if its working over there, this will help you to find the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you have not figured it out yet. Please use the code below

```
HttpPost httpPost2 = new HttpPost(yodleeURL+login);
List<NameValuePair> nvps2 =new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
System.out.println(yodleeURL+login);
nvps2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cobSessionToken", sessionToken));
nvps2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login", "xxxxxxx"));
nvps2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "xxxxxxx"));

UrlEncodedFormEntity encodedURL =  new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps2);
httpPost2.setEntity(encodedURL);
CloseableHttpResponse response2 = httpclient.execute(httpPost2);
JsonElement element1 = new      JsonParser().parse(EntityUtils.toString(response2.getEntity()));
JsonObject  jobject1 = element1.getAsJsonObject();
System.out.println(jobject1.toString());
```